# Unresolved function overload if return value not assigned to variable

Tags: c++, templates

I wrote a templated function `foo` that returns an `std::string`.

```
auto s = foo(...) << std::endl;
std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

works, but

```
std::cout << foo(...) << std::endl;
```

fails with a

> no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostrea<char>’ and ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’)

error.

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

// checks if It is an iterator type
template<typename It, typename Base = std::input_iterator_tag>
struct is_iterator : public std::is_base_of<Base, typename std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category> {};

// dummy function that takes in iterator
template<typename It, typename = typename std::enable_if_t<is_iterator<It>::value>>
std::string foo(It it) { return "foo it"; }

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1};

    // works
    auto s = foo(v.begin());
    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    // doesn't
    std::cout << (foo(v.begin())) << std::end;
}
```

Why is the call without an assignment failing? My guess is there is something wrong with my template definitions but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: `std::cout << (foo(v.begin())) << std::end;` Look at that line *very* closely, and see if you can spot the typo :)

Comment: [because **std::end** is not **std::endl**!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4d29506b9c47e0c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo. Change the line -

```
std::cout << (foo(v.begin())) << std::end;
```

into -

```
std::cout << (foo(v.begin())) << std::endl;
```